# scala Option[Int] primitive Boxing and Unboxing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, boxing

Hi I have a question regarding boxing and IntelliJ de-sugar menu.

So when I wrap a Int for example in to a Scala Option I expect that the primitive would get boxed once but when I de-sugar the Scala code in IntelliJ I get a value boxed like 5 or more times

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  
     val a: Option[Int] = Some(1)    
  }
}
```

Now when I use the De-sugar menu I get this code

```
object App {
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val a: Option[Int] = Some.apply(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        Predef.Integer2int(scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(
        1
        )))))))))))))))))))))

 }
}
```

Which has the primitive box lots of times. Now this seems like it would bloat my code.

Why would it need to box the Option[Int] so many times.

Comment: When Looking a byte code I can only see the Boxing of the Int once. So I then clicked the de-sugar menu and recompiled and when looking at the Byte Code the 2nd time I could see it boxed many times. So I think it may be a issue with IntelliJ de-sugar menu that is not working correctly .

Comment: thanks for format I did not notice I will keep in mind next time I submit request. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug and has been accepted as bug by IntelliJ

[Bug ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13679)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange, could it be an artefact of IntelliJ ?

Using scala 2.12.5 in the command line as:

```
./scala -Xprint:typer -e "val a: Option[Int] = Some(1)"
```

It seems to produce a single call:

```
private[this] val a: Option[Int] = scala.Some.apply[Int](1);
```

Full result being:

```
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // scalacmd4175089397487439052.scala
package <empty> {
  object Main extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Main.type = {
      Main.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      final class $anon extends scala.AnyRef {
        def <init>(): <$anon: AnyRef> = {
          $anon.super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        private[this] val a: Option[Int] = scala.Some.apply[Int](1);
        <stable> <accessor> private def a: Option[Int] = $anon.this.a
      };
      {
        new $anon();
        ()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've submitted a Bug report to JetBrains its on YouTrack now. Its the Scala plugin, So I don't think the compiler is boxing so many times.